# Can't build Java EE project using org.wildfly:wildfly-spec-api dependency

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-10

I have Java EE 7 application deployed to WildFly 10.1.0.Final

I have the following Maven configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>payment</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>payment</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-spec-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-webdriver</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>payment</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

I type

```
mvn clean package
```

and I get following error

> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Downloading:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/wildfly/wildfly-spec-api/10.1.0.Final/wildfly-spec-api-10.1.0.Final.jar
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 2.262 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2018-01-10T15:50:43+01:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 20M/399M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project payment: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project mycompany:payment:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not
>   find artifact org.wildfly:wildfly-spec-api:jar:10.1.0.Final in central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To
>   see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug
>   logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and
>   possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help
>   1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

How can I fix my project? I can't use javax:javaee-api dependency because when I use it IntelliJ misbehaves.

Comment: What's wrong with the maven?

Comment: `org.wildfly:wildfly-spec-api` is a pom type dependency.

Comment: @FedericoSierra, what does it change? Should I use it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to comment from Federico Sierra and quick help from WildFly JIRA I know I was missing

```
<type>pom</type>
```

So it should be

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-spec-api</artifactId>
        <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```